# How to get all resources of a page in ruby

Tags: ruby, http

There are many http request tools in ruby, httparty, rest-client, etc.  But most of them get only the page itself.  Is there a tool that gets the html, javascript, css and images of a page just like a browser does?

Comment: Is this page local to your app, or out in the wild?

Comment: What's the purpose? In other words, what specifically are you trying to do, and why Ruby? Something like wget might suit your needs, depending on what your needs actually are. Otherwise it's a matter of recursion, or using a browser driver or headless browser. It also depends on whether or not you need to *run* the JavaScript, e.g., for dynamically-loaded content.

Comment: It's obvious the purpose is to download entire pages from a site. The intent is harder to fathom since most pages are chock-full of copyrighted material, but what is done with it is the OP's karma.

Comment: Your question isn't defined well enough. What do you need to do once the files are on disk? How much do you know about writing this sort of code -- nothing or you are capable of plugging together pieces? Answering you could take an entire book, since there are few apps, if any, available in Ruby that do what you want.

Comment: @theTinMan The purpose ("The reason for which something is done [...]") cannot be obvious, because it isn't stated, hence my question. The reason would be what would drive my answer. For example, if the purpose was to have a page that could be interacted with, I'd recommend something like Capybara etc. If it was to grab a complete page to have it locally, I'd ask "why Ruby" (like I did). Etc.

Answer (score 0):

[Anemone](http://anemone.rubyforge.org/) comes to mind, but it's not designed to do a single page. It's capable if you have the time to set it up though.

It's not hard to retrieve the content of a page using something like Nokogiri, which is a HTML parser. You can iterate over tags that are of interest, grab their "SRC" or "HREF" parameters and request those files, storing their content on disk.

A simple, untested and written-on-the-fly, example using Nokogiri and OpenURI would be:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

html = open('http://www.example.com').read
File.write('www.example.com.html', html)
page = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
page.search('img').each do |img|
  File.open(img['src'], 'wb') { |fo| fo.write open(img['src']).read }
end
```

Getting CSS and JavaScript are a bit more difficult because you have to determine whether they are embedded in the page or are resources and need to be retrieved from their sources.

Merely downloading the HTML and content is easy. Creating a version of the page that is stand-alone and reads the content from your local cache is much more difficult. You have to rewrite all the "SRC" and "HREF" parameters to point to the file on your disk.

If you want to be able to locally cache a site, it's even worse, because you have to re-jigger all the anchors and links in the pages to point to the local cache. In addition you have to write a full site spider which is smart enough to stay within a site, not follow redundant links, obey a site's ROBOTS file, and not consume all your, or their, bandwidth and get you banned, or sued.

As the task grows you also have to consider how you are going to organize all the files. Storing one page's resources in one folder is sloppy, but the easy way to do it. Storing resources for two pages in one folder becomes a problem because you can have filename collisions for different images or scripts or CSS. At that point you have to use multiple folders, or switch to using a database to track the locations of the resources, and rename them with unique identifiers, and rewrite those back to your saved HTML, or write an app that can resolve those requests and return the correct content.